# How to change class styles based on previous class element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to change the button class styles only when the input is getting the validation class:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class=input-box>
        <input class="input-validation-error">
    </div>
    <button class="filterbarcode" />
</div>
```

Comment: No, you can't do that with just CSS because CSS selectors can select only elements that are child/descendant/sibling of the reference element. Here, the `input` is neither of those with respect to the `button`.

Comment: Yes "Harry" is right you can not do that only with css.

Comment: @akash: I think you hadn't read my comment fully. I had already stated that we can select siblings but here the `input` is **not a sibling** of the button.